# How to adjust column width In openxml Library

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-core-webapi, openxml, openxml-sdk

```
    using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create($"{masterType}.xlsx", SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
    {

      WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.AddWorkbookPart();
      workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

      WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
      var sheetData = new SheetData();
      worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(sheetData);

      Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());
      Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = $"{masterType}" };

      sheets.Append(sheet);

      Row headerRow = new Row() { };


      List<String> columns = new List<string>();
      foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in table.Columns)
      {
        columns.Add(column.ColumnName);
        Cell cell = new Cell();
        cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
        cell.CellValue = new CellValue(column.ColumnName);

        headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
      }
      sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);
      foreach (DataRow dsrow in table.Rows)
      {
        Row newRow = new Row() { Height = 10, };
        foreach (String col in columns)
        {
          Cell cell = new Cell();
          cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
          cell.CellValue = new CellValue(dsrow[col].ToString());
          newRow.AppendChild(cell);
        }
        sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
      }

    }
```

Data is successfully exporting to excel but i am unable to set column width. Iam using latest version of openxml library 2.20.0v.can you tell how to adjust column width.Data is successfully exporting to excel but i am unable to set column width. Iam using latest version of openxml library 2.20.0v.can you tell how to adjust column width.Data is successfully exporting to excel but i am unable to set column width. Iam using latest version of openxml library 2.20.0v.can you tell how to adjust column width.